# Using preg_replace to change javascript onclick window location data

Tags: javascript, php, preg-replace

I'm wanting to change the window location inside a dynamically generated div that has a onclick window location function, here is the div code;

```
<div class="buynow" id="item-1" onclick="window.location='store.php?id=1'">
```

I'm hoping to be able to use preg_replace to change the window location to something like;

```
<div class="buynow" id="item-1" onclick="window.location='item-one/'">
```

I've tried a few methods and failed miserably. Any tips on how I could achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: From where do you get the value `item-one`?

Comment: It's an attempt to create clean, SEO friendly URL's sitewide, the window location mysite.com/item-one/ is a .htaccess rewrite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$str = "<div class=\"buynow\" id=\"item-1\" onclick=\"window.location='store.php?id=1'\">";

echo preg_replace("/(<div.*?window\.location=)('.+')(.*?>)/", "\\1'item-one/'\\3", $str);
```

[Working Example](http://regex101.com/r/cE6iA8)

Edit: added missing $.

Comment: This looks the most promising, but it's giving me a "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=' in your code" for "str = " on my website, and see here: http://phpcodechecker.com/ - thanks.

Comment: My mistake, simple overlook by me, missing $ before str. Thanks heaps.

Answer (score 0):

Try like so:

```
preg_replace('/(window\.location=\')[^"]+?(\'")/i', '\1item-one/\2', '<div class="buynow" id="item-1" onclick="window.location=\'store.php?id=1\'">');
```